# Using a ES6 class instead of a constant and export it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm a little confused about coding with classes in ES6. Suppose I want to create a simple library similar to JS. I create a module like so in my library.js:

```
const $ = (...args) => {
    if (typeof args[0] === 'function') {
    const docReadyFn = args[0];

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', docReadyFn);
  }
}

module.exports = $;
```

I then require this file in index.js:

```
const $ = require('./library');

module.exports = $;
```

And use it in another file:

```
const $ = require('./library');

$(() => {
    console.log('DOM ready!');
});
```

However, instead of doing `const $ = (...args) => { ... }` I want to make a class with a constructor like this:

```
class Library {
    constructor(...args) {
        if (typeof args[0] === 'function') {
            const docReadyFn = args[0];

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', docReadyFn);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Library;
```

Is it wise to do it this way? And with classes I have to create a new instance with `new Library(args)`, but with by exporting `const $ = (...args) => { ... }` I can simply use `$` without doing anything. No new instance or anything. How can I use classes to achieve the same thing as creating a const and exporting that and using it right away?

Comment: A class is not a function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Is there a way to use classes in order to achieve something like this? I think classes are nicer and make the code more organized.

Comment: module.exports = (...args) => new Library(...args);

Answer (score 2):

A `class` must always be called with `new`, and will create a new instance.
Your `$` function does not create objects - it should not be a `class`.